# (PHP, MYSQL) Result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

Having problem with my php code on line 111 (line 15 from start of php), tried changing it to both int/string but nothing works. 
Here is the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

   $hotel = $_POST["hotel"];
   $username = $_SESSION["username"];
   $score = $_POST["score"];
   $explain= $_POST["explain"];
   $hotelid = mysqli_query($con, "select HoteID from hotel where hotelname='$hotel'");
   $usernameid = mysqli_query($con, "select UserID from user where UserID='$username'");

   $sql = "INSERT INTO user
             (description, score, userID, HoteID)
           VALUES
             ('$explain','$score','$usernameid','$hotelid')";

    if($con->query($sql)){
        header('Location: review.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why one additional closing `}` ?

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar my fault, i forgot to add the if(isset at the top)

Comment: Please can you review your code and post the correct code snippet. At the moment you have an extra `}` before the `?>`.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns a result set (i.e. `$usernameid`), you try and use this directly in your `$sql` statement.  You need to fetch the data to be able to do this.

Comment: @JustIce yes i just did

Comment: Which line of what you pasted here throws the error ? Also, I think your queries aren't secure and could suffer from SQL injections

Comment: Check `$hotelid` and `$usernameid` queries. May be these are giving you more than one result.

Comment: I guess you should add $sql = "INSERT INTO user(description, score, userID, HoteID)
 VALUES('$explain','$score','$usernameid[0]','$hotelid[0]')";

Comment: @AymDev Values('') line throws the error, no problem with the sql injection, just a school project to learn sql and php

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar, that did now work, now i got a second error (( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for) aswell

Comment: Check my answer. I have given it separate

Comment: `scream.enabled = off` add this setting in php.ini

Comment: Please don't just disable things as they are inconvenient, these things are there for a reason.  `@` should normally be removed and any errors handled rather than ignored.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query returns object and you cannot insert it directly, so use
mysqli_fetch_array as shown below

```
$hotelid = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "select HoteID from
    hotel where hotelname='$hotel'"));

$usernameid = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "select UserID
from user where UserID='$username'"));

$sql = "INSERT INTO user(description, score, userID, HoteID) 
VALUES('$explain','$score','$usernameid[UserID]','$hotelid[HoteID]')";
```

Comment: I got 4 errors on line 106 and 107 (the hotelid and username id) "( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for" And ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\..."

Comment: Please check whether values of variables ($hotel,$username) is empty or not

Comment: I tried echo'ing them and they returned nothing

Comment: since variable are empty you will get that warning so check posted values and session variable

Comment: I echoed them and they outputed what i wanted them to output, but i also talked with my teacher about the problem, he thought the error was fine as long as i understood the fundimentals of PHP and MySql. I'm already way ahead of my class anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using procedural way

```
$usernameid = mysqli_query($con, "select UserID from user where UserID='$username'");
```

And here you are using OOP way

```
if($con->query($sql)){
```

If you are using procedural way

Change

```
 if($con->query($sql)){
```

With

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
```

And put given below code

```
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($hotelid);
 $result1=mysqli_fetch_array($usernameid);
 $hotelid=$result['HoteID'];
 $usernameid=$result1['UserID'];
```

after

```
$usernameid = mysqli_query($con, "select UserID from user where UserID='$username'");
```

Comment: ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:

Answer (score 0):

Please change your sql to :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(description, score, userID, HoteID) VALUES('$explain','$score',$usernameid['UserID'],$hotelid['HoteID'])";
```

You might be getting usernameid and hotelid in array form.